# Permanently enable just my code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using visual studio 2010, and every time I open it, "just my code" under tools->options->debugging is disabled. Does anyone know how to permanently enable this?

I have the following extensions enabled if this makes any difference:

.NET reflector visual studio extension; NuGet package manager; process template editor; productivity power tools; specflow; WITDesigner

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After some further digging around on google, it turns out that this is cause by the .NET reflector plugin. After disabling reflector, just my code remains enabled when VS is closed and opened.

Comment: Just for anyone who comes along later: In the .NET Reflector menu, there's a "Disable Just My Code on Startup" option. You can uncheck that instead of disabling Reflector entirely.

Comment: To "disable" .net reflector, I had to go to "Programs and Features" and uninstall the .Net Reflector Plugin for VS.  In my case, I only had the trial version which had expired a while ago.  Thanks for leading me to this solution!

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue with ANTS profiler. Is there any way to "disable" the profiler without uninstall it?